# Помогите с выборкой из mysql по ключу JSON

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

Коллеги, прошу помощи. Есть таблица mySQL, в которой есть N записей формата id(bigint), name (varchar) и options (JSON).
Структура данных для options у всех элементов примерно такая:

```
[
  {
    "value": "1000",
    "option": "echo"
    } ,
  {
    "value": "123",
    "option": "id"
    } ,
  {
    "value": "2",
    "option": "test"
    }
  ]
```

Нужен запрос, который выведет id всех элементов таблицы, где value для ключа test >= 2

Comment: SELECT * FROM table WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(options, '$.option') = 'test' AND JSON_EXTRACT(options, '$.value') >=2

Comment: Спасибо, так я пробовал, ошибки нет, но и результат не выдает. Я формирую сам json из массива php фнкцией json_encode, может со структурой что не так?

Comment: Точная версия MySQL? *Структура данных для options у всех элементов примерно такая:* Примерно? или "абсолютно точно у всех как минимум такая, возможно наличие в массиве неуказанных объектов"?

Comment: @Vadim Ваш запрос неверен - он не гарантирует, что значения для отдельных частей условия взяты из одного объекта.

Comment: Версия mysql 5.7.21.

Comment: в массиве могут быть и больше пар option:value

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался сам. JSON_EXTRACT не работает с повторяющимися ключами без "родительского ключа".

привел структуру JSON к такому виду:

{
"prm1": {
"value": "10",
"option": "test"
},
"prm2": {
"value": "390х140х390",
"option": "Размер"
}
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(options, '$.prm1.value') >= 2 AND JSON_EXTRACT(options, '$.prm1.option') = 'test' ";

Запрос работает отлично.